# No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Uri'.

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this model:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Link { get; set; }
}
```

I added it to `fluent-api` using the following code:

```
 builder.Entity<Book>(entity => {
     entity.HasKey(b => b.Id);
 });
```

when I run this:

```
add-migration InitialMigration -context MyAppContext
```

then I get:

> No suitable constructor found for entity type 'Uri'. The following parameters could not be bound to properties of the entity: 'uriString', 'uriString', 'dontEscape', 'baseUri', 'relativeUri', 'dontEscape', 'uriString', 'uriKind', 'baseUri', 'relativeUri', 'serializationInfo', 'streamingContext', 'baseUri', 'relativeUri', 'flags', 'uriParser', 'uri'.

Comment: Since Uri is not a flat type, it has to be mapped to another table with columns matching its properties. However, for EF to be able to do the mapping (especially materializing values), all mapped properties have to have a setter and the entity type has to have a parameterless constructor, which is not the case with Uri.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: Either create a POCO class that can track the (necessary) properties of Uri or use a type that can be converted to and fit into a single column.

Comment: what exactly means POCO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't persist a `Uri` directly to the database, as there's no associated SQL type for that. You need to use a string instead. If you're using a view model (as you should be), your view model can have the `Uri`, and then you simply need to get the string representation during your mapping to your actual entity type.

You can also simply utilize EF Core's value conversion (available in 2.1+). See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) for more detail. Essentially, in your fluent config:

```
.HasConversion(
    v => v.ToString(),
    v => new Uri(v));
```

Answer (score 3):

A value conversion can be added to your `DbContext` to convert the type used when reading from or writing to the database. This is done by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Book>()
        .Property(e => e.Link)
        .HasConversion(v => v.ToString(), v => new Uri(v));
}
```